# How to replace a string to a set of one characters

Tags: java, string, for-loop, extract, string-length

How do I replace an inputted string word to a set of one character:
For example:

The string is: Hello Word
The output should be: aaaaa aaaa

**The space should remain a space.**

I've tried this one but there's no space.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String word =  input.nextLine();

for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){                 
    System.out.print("a");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps

```
System.out.println("Hello Word".replaceAll("\\S", "a"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
   System.out.print(word.charAt(i) == ' ' ? ' ' : 'a');
}
```

or if you need the result after the loop then you could use a `StringBuilder` as the accumulator and then print.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
    builder.append(word.charAt(i) == ' ' ? ' ' : 'a'); // accumulate to builder
}
System.out.println(builder);
```

or you could go the Java-8 way:

```
System.out.println(word.chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> ((char)c) == ' ' ? " " : "a")
            .collect(joining()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate each character in `word`, if it is white-space print it without modification. Otherwise, print `a`. Like,

```
for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
        System.out.print(ch);
    } else {
        System.out.print('a');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String word =  input.nextLine();

for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){ 
    if(word.charAt(i) == ' '){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    else{
        System.out.print("a");
    }
}
```

Basically, you want to skip the System.out.print("a") whenever you encounter a space.

Comment: The OP said "The space should remain a space."

Answer (score 0):

This method would replace any string to any wanted character you wanted besides spaces.

```
    public static void main(String []args) {
        String t = "Hello Word";
        replace(t, 'a');
    }

    public static void replace(String word, char wanted) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
            System.out.print((word.charAt(i) == ' ' ? " " : wanted));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could iterate `word.toCharArray()` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "Hello World!";
    String replacedWord = "";

    for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
        if (c != ' ') {
            replacedWord += 'a';
        } else {
            replacedWord += c;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(word + " --> " + replacedWord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well at this point why don't add a solution using the lambdas

```
public String goofy(String str) {
    return Stream.of(str.split("")).map(ch -> {
            if (ch.equals(" "))
                return " ";
            else
                return "a";
}).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
}
```

btw the most practical solution is the one from @Reimeus that anticipated me.

Comment: You could reduce the code quite a bit to `return Arrays.stream(str.split(""))
                .map(ch -> ch.equals(" ") ? " " : "a")
                .collect(Collectors.joining());`. note the use of `Arrays.stream` which is the idiomatic approach to proceed with when you're creating a stream from an existing array (which the `split` method returns) as opposed to `Stream.of` which is used to create a "Stream from explicitly typed values". further, in the `joining` collector you don't need to specify the delimiter when it's `""` just don't pass one at all. Otherwise nice idea :) .

Comment: You are right, I went for the long and plain and didactic version with the logic stack in the middle of the function. But you are totally right. 

You can do it also very very short just passing trough a Stream of int with the String.chars method at the cost of a casting

Answer (score 0):

We should be using code points rather than chars.

```
System.out.println(
        "Hello, world!".codePoints()
        .mapToObj(Character::isWhiteSpace)
        .map(Map.of(true, " ", false, "a")::get)  // yeah I know, but just to be goofy
        .collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
String word=input.nextLine();
String x[] =word.split(" ");
int count=x.length;

for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<=x[i].length();j++){
       if(j==x[i].length()){
           System.out.print(" ");
       }else{
           System.out.print("a");
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if(word.charAt(i) != ' ') {
        System.out.print("a");
    }
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```